# ggplot Removing white area around graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I want to remove white area around graph in ggplot. plot.background and plot.margin don't work there.

This is my plot (huge white area on the left and right of graph). I add black outline in paint.
[image]

And I want to ggplot save my plot like below
[image]

There is my code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(grid)
srednia<- c(39,17,13)
plus<-srednia+2
minus<-srednia-2
nazwa<-c("name")
labels2<-c("1", "2", "3")
bars=srednia
  df<- data.frame(labels2,srednia, plus, minus, bars)

  ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(labels2), y = srednia, dodge=factor(labels2))) +
  ################################################################################
  labs(title = nazwa, size=3)+   theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust=2.5))+ 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=0, color="black", size=8, vjust=.5))+
  ################################################################################
  ylab("Fold change")+theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(.5), face="italic"))+
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(.5), face="italic"))+ xlab("Cell line") +
    ####################################################################################
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'red', angle = 0, 
                                   size = 5, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, face = 'italic'))+
    ###############################################################################
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'red', angle = 0, 
                                   size = 5, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, face = 'italic'))+
    #################################################################################
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size = .2))+
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+ 
    theme(axis.line=element_line(colour="black",size=.2))+
    ###################################################################################
  geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(labels2)),alpha=I(.5),stat="identity",fill=labels2, 
           colour=scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.1,0))+
    geom_text(aes(label=bars), size = 2, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 7, position ="stack",                colour="white")+
    ###############################################################################
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(minus), ymax=(plus)), size=.3, linetype="dashed")+
    #############################################################################
  theme(plot.background=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
        plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"in"))+coord_equal(1/5)


  ggsave("graph.png",width=3, height=2.5)
```

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: `ggsave("graph.png", width=1.5, height=2.5)` removed the `spaces` for me

Comment: yes this is work, there is no extra white space but then graph change widht/height ratio, I want to 1.5/2,5

Comment: @Bartex Taciak  You may need to check `x11`